# Linq Left Join Throws Error Saying 'There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first.'

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, blazor

I am trying to retrieve list by doing left join in linq.

But the problem is that the join throws an error

> There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first

Any help to fix this issue will be grateful. Thank you.

Below is my linq left join

```
    public List<UserVsFriendVM> GetAllMessageUserList1()
    {
        var getList = (from mu in uow.Repository<MessageUser>().GetAll()
                       join f in uow.Repository<Friend>().GetAll().Where(x => x.IsConfirmed != 2) on mu.MessageUserName equals f.FriendRequestSenderName into a
                       from b in a.DefaultIfEmpty()
                       select new UserVsFriendVM
                       {
                           Id = mu.Id,
                           MessageUserName = mu.MessageUserName,
                           IsConfirmed = b == null? 0:b.IsConfirmed,

                       }).ToList();
        return getList;
    }
```

Comment: Can you please add code for `GetAll()`?

Comment: Does `GetAll` returns `IQueryable<T>` ?

Comment: public IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
        {
            return _dbset.AsEnumerable();
        }

Comment: Just FYI `AsEnumerable` will fetch all the data from table into memory. Usually you should not do that.

Comment: Looks like another case of the "generic repository" antipattern. Those `GetAll` methods load the entire table in memory. That's a **major** bug. Imagine having even a small 10K-row table. Are you going to load everything in memory every time?

Answer (score 1):

Based on definition of `GetAll` method provided in comments, i.e.:

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetAll() { return _dbset.AsEnumerable(); }
```

And assumption that all repositories share db context (for example if it is registered as scoped) you will end up having to simultaneous queries running on the same context which will result in the error you are getting. One way to fix it is to return `IQueryable` from the repo:

```
public IQueryable<T> GetAll() { return _dbset; }
```

Also this implementation will actually perform queries on the db side and not client side which usually should result in better performance of the app.

Also based on that I would say that repository pattern will be [redundant](https://www.thereformedprogrammer.net/is-the-repository-pattern-useful-with-entity-framework-core/) here (I would say that it still up to debate if it is in general not useful in pair with EF, though) and you can just build your queries directly:

```
from mu in dbContext.MessageUsers // assuming the name here
join f in dbContext.Friends.Where(x => x.IsConfirmed != 2) on mu.MessageUserName equals f.FriendRequestSenderName into a
from b in a.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new UserVsFriendVM
{
    Id = mu.Id,
    MessageUserName = mu.MessageUserName,
    IsConfirmed = b == null? 0:b.IsConfirmed,
}
```

Comment: Even the join is redundant - if the entities have proper relations, EF will generate the necessary JOINs itself.